# It is possible to compare between two list value using For Loop and If Statement only?

Tags: python, arrays

The value between two list as shown below:

```
testlist = [1,3,5,7]
WinCombination = [ [7,5,3],[1,2,3],[3,5,7]]
```

I want to detect the value of [**3,5,7**] in WinCombination and it also exist in testArray = [1,**3,5,7**] with the same order. I cannot figure out the way to test between this list. I am beginner in Python. Thanks for helping

Comment: @MadPhysicist. Thank you for reminding me. I will improve my question in future. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you should use [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) to get the combinations from the lenght, convert `WinCombinations` to a `list` of tuples and check every time if the combination is in the list.

in this case i used [`list comprehension`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) in this case but you can also use the normal loop instead:

```
import itertools
testArray = [1,3,5,7]
WinCombination = [ [7,5,3],[1,2,3],[3,5,7]]
lentocheck=3

combined=[x for x in itertools.combinations(testArray,lentocheck) if x in list(map(tuple,WinCombination))]    
print(combined)
```

output:

```
[(3, 5, 7)]
```

i had to convert `WinCombinations` to a list of tuples because `itertools.combinations` returns a list of tuples, in this way i can do the comparison.

Comment: alright, Thanks. I will try this way too. It look little bit complex but I try my best to understand this way. Thanks again

Comment: you should checkmark my answer, if you consider this as a valid answer.

Answer (score 0):

whatever i understood from your question that you want to find a combination from testList in wincombination with same order..may be below code can help you.

```
wincombination=[[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[6,5,4]]
testArray=[1,2,3,4]
flag=False
for i in wincombination:
    if i==testArray[1:]:
        print("present")
        flag=True
if flag==True:
    print("not present")
```

Comment: thanks. Actually I already do some "post-mortem" for your code. It easier to understand. However, can I know what is mean using value 1 with semicolon in line if i == testArray[1:]: .

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple way to get this done, it's just by comparing the str values of sequences.

```py
str_test = str(testlist)[1:-1]
matches = [combination for combination in WinCombination
           if str(combination)[1:-1] in str_test]
```

this will match every sub-array from **testlist** that is present in **WinCombination** by verifying if the string of testlist is a superset of combination string, the slicing [1:-1] is just to keep out brackets from string.